# Why the card hover is out from the container?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

The problem is when I hover the cursor to the card the hover card are out from the main container which avoid me to click the navigation bar.
[image: the issue]

I have try to put inside the v-content and v-container but still not working.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <v-container grid-list-md>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs6 md4 sm4 lg3 xl2 v-for="n in 12" :key="n" class="pa-2">
          <v-hover>
            <v-card
              slot-scope="{ hover }"
              :class="`elevation-${hover ? 12 : 2}`"
              class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg"
            >
              <v-img
                src="https://www.candere.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/r/gr00237_1_2.jpg"
              >
                <v-chip class="ma-2" small color="#e5af57" text-color="black">916</v-chip>
              </v-img>
              <v-card-text>
                <table style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <h4 class="text-sm-center">Bunga Emas Arau</h4>
                    </td>
                    <br>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <v-divider></v-divider>
                    </td>
                    <br>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="font-weight-small">
                    <td>Weight Approx.</td>
                    <td>2.37 g +/-</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="font-weight-medium">
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>RM300-2300</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-fade-transition>
                <v-overlay v-if="hover" absolute color="#190033">
                  <v-btn color="#d19f4e">See more info</v-btn>
                </v-overlay>
              </v-fade-transition>
            </v-card>
          </v-hover>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want the hover to stay inside and doesn't interrupt the main navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `z-index="0"` to `<v-overlay></v-overlay>`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6 md4 sm4 lg3 xl2 v-for="n in 12" :key="n" class="pa-2">
        <v-hover>
          <v-card slot-scope="{ hover }" :class="`elevation-${hover ? 12 : 2}`" class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
            <v-img src="https://www.candere.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/r/gr00237_1_2.jpg">
              <v-chip class="ma-2" small color="#e5af57" text-color="black">916</v-chip>
            </v-img>
            <v-card-text>
              <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <h4 class="text-sm-center">Bunga Emas Arau</h4>
                  </td>
                  <br>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <v-divider></v-divider>
                  </td>
                  <br>
                </tr>
                <tr class="font-weight-small">
                  <td>Weight Approx.</td>
                  <td>2.37 g +/-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="font-weight-medium">
                  <td>Price</td>
                  <td>RM300-2300</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-fade-transition>
              <v-overlay v-if="hover" absolute color="#190033" z-index="0">
                <v-btn color="#d19f4e">See more info</v-btn>
              </v-overlay>
            </v-fade-transition>
          </v-card>
        </v-hover>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a z-index problem for the v-overlay element. Try lowering the z-index prop for the v-overlay.